# Calculating the Big O of this code snippet

Tags: java, time-complexity

So I have a line of code that's calling several methods and I'd like to know in total, what is the time-complexity of it, the Big O.

```
List<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("cities.txt")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Basically I'm trying to read the file "cities.txt" and storing each text line of it in a different element on the list.

Comment: What do you mean by 'complexity'? Do you want to know if it works linearly or more you asked about multithreading?

Comment: Looks simple to me.

Comment: Yeah, I was asking about the Big O of this line of code. Guess It was kind of ambiguous the way i asked

Comment: It's O(n). Here are more characters so SO will accept my comment.